# MySQL query results in PHP differ to those in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, character-encoding

I have some UTF-8 characters that were stored incorrectly in my MySQL database, e.g. `£` is stored as `Â£`. Since there are too many to manually correct I want to run a query via PHP to get the affected rows and use regular expressions to replace them.

The basic query I am using to test this is:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `notes` 
 WHERE `notes` LIKE '%Â£%';
```

If I run this in phpMyAdmin it returns 754 rows, but in my PHP script it only returns 5 rows:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `notes` LIKE '%Â£%'";
$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
echo "rows... " . mysqli_num_rows($result));
```

I also tried setting the character set:

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf-8');
```

Why does the same query to the same database produce different results?

Comment: You probably need to use `SET CHARSET` after opening the connection.

Comment: `'utf-8'` is not a valid charset. Please use `utf8mb4` and make sure your database columns are also set to it.

Comment: @Dharman thank you that fixes the issue, do you want to answer the question for the full credit

Comment: I already gave you the answer. It's linked at the top of the page. It's called canonical and it should help you solve the problem

Comment: "myPHPAdmin" does not exist. Pay attention to details and you'll notice _phpMyAdmin_ will also tell you at one place that it uses `utf8m4` or `utf8`, and not "utf-8".